# module object has no attribute 'thread'

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multithreading

I was using basic threading.
This was the code I typed.

```
#!usr/bin/python3

import threading
class Bhai_ka_messenger(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        for message in range(10):
            print threading.currentThread().getName()

a=Bhai_ka_messenger(name="message send")
b=Bhai_ka_messenger(name="message receive")
a.start()
b.start()
```

This says module object has no attribute thread.
When I run this on an online IDE, this program works.
Now I am not able to sort this problem,can anyone help?

Comment: You have a local file called "threading.py".

Answer (score 7):

You have called your local file `threading.py`, but then import that file inside the file itself, causing it not to work.

I hope this can help you.